# Gviz only showing first part of fusion table on Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I modified one of Geocodezip's examples to use my fusion table.  The table is 40+ rows but only the first 11 are displaying on the map.  Everything geocodes OK from within the fusion table but not here.  Can someone please explain why.

http://6tango.com/Map_Examples/fusion_with_geocode.html

[EDIT]  I just noticed that Geocodezip's example only has 11 points.  Guess I'd better look at his javascript closer.

On another note, is there an easy way to show a block of code here without manually adding spaces to each line? (please excuse my ignorance)

PS - Thank you Geocodezip for all your examples.  For a newbie like me they are a God-send!

Answer (score 0):

You are geocoding the entries in the table on the fly, check for the case when status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK, you will find you are getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT responses.

I would suggest geocoding the addresses offline (or capturing the coordinates from the points that are displayed) and adding the resulting coordinates in additional columns of the table to avoid the problem.